# KeyError: 'Requested level (Medal) does not match index name (Team)'

Tags: python, pandas

This line of code gives me a distribution of countries by medals won during the last 100 years of Olympics:

```
atl.groupby('Team')['Medal'].count().nlargest(20).plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10, 10))
```

The 'Medal' column has plenty of nans, and the rest are Gold, Silver and Bronze.
I wanted to use unstack('Medal') to see the distribution by each of the medals, but getting this:

```
KeyError: 'Requested level (Medal) does not match index name (Team)'
```

The dataframe itself looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 271116 entries, 0 to 271115
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------  --------------   -----  
 0   ID      271116 non-null  int64  
 1   Name    271116 non-null  object 
 2   Sex     271116 non-null  object 
 3   Age     261642 non-null  float64
 4   Height  210945 non-null  float64
 5   Weight  208241 non-null  float64
 6   Team    271116 non-null  object 
 7   NOC     271116 non-null  object 
 8   Games   271116 non-null  object 
 9   Year    271116 non-null  int64  
 10  Season  271116 non-null  object 
 11  City    271116 non-null  object 
 12  Sport   271116 non-null  object 
 13  Event   271116 non-null  object 
 14  Medal   39783 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(10)
memory usage: 31.0+ MB
```

What am i missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: I don't know what that means...

Comment: It means you should click on the link and follow the guidance shown there.